# How can I properly assign a value to an array (of structure type) element?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, variable-assignment, compound-literals

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct virus
{
    char signature[25];
    int size;
}v[2];

int main(void) {

    static v[0] = {"Yankee",1813};
    static v[1] = {"Doodle",2813};
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n",v[i].signature,v[i].size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

I am getting the compiler error in this C code.

> Error: Declaration syntax in function `main()`

I am guessing that there is some error in `v[2]`, as it is associated with extern class whereas, `v[0]` and `v[1]` are associated with static class.

But, I am not sure that is this the only reason or some other ?

---

Edit : I have edited the code by removing the wrong syntax.

Comment: You need to spend several hours or days reading about the C programming language. Don't touch your keyboard before that.

Comment: remove `static` too in ` main`

Comment: @ammoQ Removing that still does not help. Error still exists .

Comment: @Barry Sorry, my mistake. Initialisation e.g. `struct xyz v = { 1, "foobar" };` works, but a similar looking assignment `v = { 1, "foobar" };` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no error in declaration of `v[2]`, the problem is later.

You've written

```
 static struct v[0] = {"Yankee",1813};
```

which *attempts* to define a 0-sized array, which is not allowed by default C standard.

That said, the syntax is also horribly wrong. You don't have a proper *type* there, remember, `struct` itself is not a type, it's a keyword. `struct <something>` is actually a *type*.

Then, from the logical point of view, you probably don't want a new variable altogether. In case you want to use the array elements from the `v`, just use the variable name, that's all. Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct virus
{
    char signature[25];
    int size;
}v[2] = { {"Yankee",1813}, {"Doodle",2813}}; //get it initialized, job done

int main(void) {

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n",v[i].signature,v[i].size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

will do the job in much better way, IMHO.

---

EDIT:

In case, you're interested in assigning individual elements (**not** initialization), well, you cannot use a brace-enclosed initializer for that purpose, it's not meant to be RHS operand for an assignment. You need to use a **[compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals)** for that purpose, something like

```
v[0] = (struct virus){"Yankee",1813};
v[1] = (struct virus){"Doodle",2813};
```

will also do the job.

Comment: v[0] = {"Yankee",1813};  But why this is not working also  ?

Comment: If I only write v[0] = {"Yankee",1813} . It's still not working. Can you provide some reason based on that . Besides, I got your way in your answer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks :)) Learn't something new.

Comment: @Barry you're welcome, that's the whole point of being here, inn'it? Happy learning. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh If you don't mind, Can you give me some reference for such methodology used in particularly structures !!

Comment: @Barry What sort of reference? [did you see this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/2173917)?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks !! That suffices .

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up struct definitions with variable declarations, that's sloppy practice.

Instead, use a typedef:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char signature[25];
    int size;
} virus_t;
```

Then you can declare variables of this type as you please:

```
static virus_t v[2] = 
{
  {"Yankee",1813},
  {"Doodle",2813}
};
```

Or with *designated initializers*:

```
static virus_t v[2] = 
{
  [0] = {"Yankee",1813},
  [1] = {"Doodle",2813}
};
```

Comment: Thanks !! very useful :)